Using .net4.8 project in .net8 based project
I have developed a Windows Forms application using .NET 4.8, and it is functioning well with all the required components available in .NET 4.8.
Now, I have a new requirement to enable internet-based communication between two computers. Specifically, I want to change a variable on one computer (PC1) and have the same variable update on the other computer (PC2). I am open to implementing this functionality through an API.
However, I am facing compatibility issues with different .NET versions. I would like to incorporate my Windows Forms project into an ASP.NET Core project, which uses .NET 8.0.
Unfortunately, when I add the Windows Forms project as a reference in the .NET 8.0 project (Dependencies > Add Project Reference), I encounter difficulties running the .NET 8.0 project. Is it possible to have two projects with different .NET versions within a single solution?
For instance, in my second project (an online communication app using .NET), I have written the following code:
using WindowsFormsApplication4;
Form1 form1Instance = new Form1();
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () =>
{
    string vari1 = 
    form1Instance.ReferenceNumericUpDownValue.ToString();
    return vari1;
});

app.Run();

my error when I run my app:
System.BadImageFormatException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\drive3\source\repos\remote2\remote2\bin\Debug\net8.0\WindowsFormsApplication4.exe'. Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid.'

I tried updating my windows form application to .net8 to have similar .net versions on both projects. But, the components that I have used made so many problems for me.

".Net 4.8" is .Net Framework 4.8. .Net and .Net Framework are two different runtimes. Your .Net 8 project cannot use your .Net Framework 4.8 project and the error you are receiving is expected. You can target .Net Standard 2.0 to create an assembly that can be used by both .Net 8 and .Net Framework 4.8 projects. (Aside: yes, you can have projects for different .NET runtimes and versions in one solution. A solution is just a set of projects. The projects don't have to be usable together to be in the same solution.)

.NET 8 is .NET Core 8, a completely different runtime and platform. It can't use .NET Framework assemblies. If you want to use the same assemblies in both .NET Core and .NET Framework you'll have to target .NET Standard 2.0.

Without adding it as reference just use ASP.NET as separate project and send request through API and get response

ok, But I am trying to get a variable which is in the windows form app!
I need to send its value through internet and I should be able to change its value through internet. (I am talking about 1 variable for simplicity, but I have lots of them.)

Do you want a Windows desktop application that communicates peer-to-peer with running instances of itself using HTTP?

I think there are several approaches that you can attend to .

As you might know , API needs Webserver (such as Kestrel Or IIS)
to run so you can't just build and run API method within your
winform application . you can implement your API in separated
ASP.NET API project alongside library that targets ".net standard
2.0 " ( you can't use .net framework alongside .net 8) .
You can use share DB to pass value between two computers (if they are in a
same local network) .
You can use real-time tools such as
signalR to pass data .

